# How to concat local time with the timezone and insert it into a timestamp column?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a timestamp column in the format of `2021-02-01 12:21:51.000000`, which is local time and in another column I have the timezone information as `Europe/Berlin`. What I am trying to is adding the offset to this timestamp as create a timestamp like this `2021-02-01 12:21:51.000000 +01:00` without changing  anything in the original value and the type of the column should be timestamp with time zone.

What I tried is that, I created the offset as a string and concat the 2 columns but when I turn it into timestamp, it turns into `2021-02-01 11:21:51.000000 +00:00`.

Comment: 1) What time zone is local time? ADD answer as update to question. 2) `timestamp` columns don't have a format that is created by whatever client you are using and it's settings. 3) *...he type of the column should be timestamp with time zone*. Does that mean you are storing the  concatenated value in a `timestamptz` column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `at time zone` option to convert a `timestamp` to a `timestamp with time zone`:

```
select the_timestamp_column, 
       the_timestamp_column at time zone timezone_column
from the_table;
```

Comment: This foes not solve the issue. 

`SELECT '2021-02-01 12:21:51.000000' AS timestamp_column,
       '2021-02-01 12:21:51.000000' at time zone 'Europe/Berlin' AS with_time_zone`

When I run this, it will result like this

`2021-02-01 12:21:51.000000,2021-02-01 13:21:51.000000`

What  I need is 
`2021-02-01 12:21:51.000000 +01:00`

Comment: @mbsouksu: the output will depend on the time zone of your database session: https://dbfiddle.uk/6Iotq0YI